# What doing SoapHttpClientProtocol in webservices

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

What doing SoapHttpClientProtocol  in webservices?what is  difference between proxy class and SoapHttpClientProtocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.aspx) (just scroll down to the Remarks section):

> ...When the XML Web service client calls using SOAP, the *proxy* class **must**
>   derive from **SoapHttpClientProtocol**, which derives from
>   HttpWebClientProtocol. HttpWebClientProtocol, in turn, derives from
>   WebClientProtocol...